# How can I use volume names with a space in them with tmutil in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, path, time-machine

I am trying to write a simple electron script to switch between my different time machine backups, but I have gotten somewhat stuck because `tmutil` keeps throwing errors when a volume name has a space in it, just as in

```
sudo tmutil removeexclusion -v /Volumes/MacOS Mojave
/Volumes/MacOS Mojave: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument
```

OK, that one was still pretty obvious, but now, what about

```
sudo tmutil removeexclusion -v "/Volumes/MacOS Mojave"
/Volumes/MacOS Mojave: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument
```

or even

```
sudo tmutil removeexclusion -v /Volumes/MacOS\ Mojave
/Volumes/MacOS\ Mojave: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument
```

`man tmutil` doesn't really go into any details about spaces or special characters in their documentation on those commands, escaping characters and quoting the paths are both ways to do this usually, but apparently not in this case. Quotes work when I use them on volume names without spaces, but that is not really the point here.

Comment: Seems odd. Is this any help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/in-mountain-lion-where-is-the-exclude-list-for-time-machine-stored Not a Mac user so not sure if it might be manually editable...

Comment: Why do you need to manually rotate the backups? Time Machine will naturally cycle between selected backup locations if it can see more than one, or continue to back up to a single location if it can't find the others.

Comment: There's also [TimeMachineEditor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/) which can help taking control of scheduling etc.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -al /Volumes`?  It's possible that the Mac sees the volume with a different name.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I back up only partitionwise to SD cards and time machine always tries to backup everything to every SD card. This is sort of historically grown, from a time where 1 g SD cards were a pipe dream, but I like my setup, and also don't want to spend more money on 1 g SD cards if I have a couple 512 lying around and also, as you have seen, my disk is partitioned, which, apart from the inconvenience that MacOS does not really support documents, system and applications being on different partitions, works really well for me :-D

Comment: @jimtut the output, concerning the partition in question, is `lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     1 26 Aug 13:22 MacOS Mojave -> /`, so, apart from the pointer to it being my boot partition, nothing odd

Comment: @jimtut however, now that I mentioned that, maybe, at this point, "MacOS Mojave" is simply known as "/" to the system, and it's not an issue of a space in the name at all, but of the partition being available under a different alias? I can easily edit that in my program's preferences, and let you know if that solves it...

Comment: @jimtut indeed, I did not even have to edit my program right now (a TM backup is running, so I did not want to interfere with that), but I did `sudo tmutil addexclusion -v "/"` and that did not draw an error, and then `sudo tmutil addexclusion -v "/Volumes/MacOS Catalina"` which did not cause an error either, so, although I still have not run my changed program due to the running backup, that is a strong hint that I was, indeed, just barking up the wrong tree. Spaces were probably never the problem. I'll update once again once I know for certain but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @jimtut and, indeed, I just checked out my program, adding and removing "/" instead of "/Volumes/MacOS Mojave" and everything now works as it should. Now, I only wish you had made your suggestion as a quick post in this question, instead of just a comment, so I could choose it as the accepted answer and you would get all of the glory ;-)

Comment: Haha, glad it worked, but I can’t take any credit, I didn’t even think this was your root partition, I thought you were misspelling something.   You can actually enter an Answer yourself and accept it, just to close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to some valuable help from the commenters, I was able to determine, that the partition with the space in the name was also my root partition, and as that to tmutil only visible as `/`. The first giveaway for that was running a `ls -al /Volumes`, which gave an output of

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 1 26 Aug 13:22 MacOS Mojave -> /
```

At first I didn't think too much of it, after all it's just an alias, right?

But when I ran

```
sudo tmutil addexclusion -v "/Volumes/MacOS Catalina"
```

on another partition with a space in it, which just happened to not be my root partition at the time, I did not get an error, thus eliminating the theory that the error was caused by a space *at all*. And then, running

```
sudo tmutil addexclusion -v "/"
```

succesfully excluded "MacOS Mojave", as I could see in TM's preferences pane.

Thus, in conclusion, tmutil works wonderfully with Volumes which have spaces in their names, but you have to be conscious of the root partition, which will not be addressed under its name, but as `/`. Both of those details just happened to have conspired to hide behind a smokescreen that shouted "no spaces allowed".

To answer the question as asked originally: Yes, you address names with a space either enclosed by " " or escaped with a \ .